# How to display user based on role in Another Model in Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
ROLE = (
    ('Courier', 'Courier'),
    ('Receptionist', 'Receptionist'),
    ('Admin', 'Admin')
)
user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ROLE)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.fullname






class OutgoingMail(models.Model):
    mail_ref = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    mail_to = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    courier = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mail_to
```

So, my question is : How to display employee name in Outgoing mail, based on employee role in Employee model. Only display employee where role is 'Courier' ?

[image: Like image bellow, in django admin, when i want to create outgoing mail, display employee based employee role]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on Foreign Keys inside fieldsets of Django admin You can basicly use formfield_for_foreignkey function inside your Admin class

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "courier": #courier is the foreignkey name
        kwargs["queryset"] = Employee.objects.filter(role='Courier') #role ='Courier' in choices
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I want to display courier name when i want to create outgoing mail in Admin dashboard. Example i want to to create outgoing mail, courier who display is employee that have role = 'courier'. Like image above